# How I can use MVVM with CRUD operations?

Tags: c#, mvvm

I'm trying to understand the basic MVVM design approach, but I dont' understand where is the best tips for work with CRUD operations.

a. Create a ViewModel with abstract of properties and in this ViewModel implement CRUD methods?

b. Create ViewModels base and then add properties for ObservableCollections of Viewmodel?.

Can you said me , how you i can do this, please!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With MVVM, all business logic and interaction with a data source should occur in the model.
Your ViewModel will expose the data and functionality that the View requires.

So if for example you had a button on your view that removed an item from the database, the button would bind to an ICommand instance on the ViewModel.  Once the ICommand executes, the implementation of this command will communicate with the model to make sure the item is deleted.  The viewmodel is then populated with the new data to allow the view to update.

Comment: So, for example, when I add another operation (say a Search method), I will create that in a service class in the model folder (where the CRUD is in, say EmployeeService.cs), then in the ViewModel, I will also create a reference for that new method right?

Answer (score 0):

I have found this gem here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mtdiDXhqhso&list=PL0wefbX90CmYNrO67FtZNDlnSrmWkF4bJ&index=1

This is WPF with MVVM.

What you'll learn here:

- CRUDS in a List/Observable collection
- CRUDS using ADO.NET
- CRUDS using Entity framework

I know that this post already has an accepted answer, but for future dev's, learning MVVM will not be easy (looking for resources that is straight to the point). That's why I posted this to share to everyone good knowledge.

Comment: this video is no longer available.